# changing checkbox color and text in angular based on condition

Tags: angular, typescript

how do we change the checkbox color and text color based on condition as you can see on my current output the checkbox is checked but the check icon is gone..for example when checkbox is check I should see the check in the box but right now its hidden.. and also if checkbox is checkd the text color should be from white to black. Thanks.

#current output
[image]

#my target design (this sould look like this)
[image]

```
<div *ngFor="let subtenant of currentSubtenants; let i = index;" class="subtenant-form-btn-group"  [ngClass]="{'v-bg-color': currentSelectedTenants(subtenant)}">
              <div class="deal-form-btn-group-radio">
                <div class="pharmacy-checkbox">
                  <mat-checkbox
                   color="accent"  
                   [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.currentSubtenants"
                   [checked]="currentSelectedTenants(subtenant)" 
                   (change)="changeCurrentSubtenants($event,subtenant)"
                   style="margin-left:10px;">
                  <mat-label class="subtenant-label" style="color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)">{{subtenant.subtenantName}}</mat-label>
                  </mat-checkbox>  
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div >
                <div class="flex-column">
                  <mat-label class="subtenant-label">Current Lease Expiration</mat-label>
                  <div class="subtenant-label">{{subtenant.currentLeaseExpiration}}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ngClass for this.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

```html
<div
  *ngFor="let subtenant of currentSubtenants; let i = index;" 
  class="subtenant-form-btn-group"
  [ngClass]="{yourClassName: dealDispositionFormFields.currentSubtenants}"
  >
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: how about for the checkbox ?

Comment: I wanna make it the same with the second pic

Comment: you would handle that with your css.

Comment: if you provide a stackblitz it would be much easier to demo the changes needed, but with the limited info, this is the best i can do.

Comment: do you have some example scenario on blitz that has the same scenario with mine ?